# how to check in if condition if the the word entered by the user is present in the array assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

please refer to line 2 after comment.
this issue is mentioned in the code in comments.

```
//valid input to be taken by user
var validanswerone = ["yes" , "YES", "Yes"];//here i want to take multiple form of input the user might type but my efforts are going effort less.
var validanswertwo = "no";//only this is working.

//conditions
if (userage === validanswerone){
  console.log("\n\nPlease put your credit card details in the next page" + ", you will be redirected soon!");
}
else if(userage === validanswertwo){
  console.log("\n\nWe are sorry!");
  console.log("\n\nPlease try back in" + "  *days remaining to be become 18+ will be added in the coming update still not understood the formula to implicate it*");
}
else{
  console.log("\n\nInvalid input!")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validanswerone` is an array, you should check it with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if (validanswerone.includes(userage)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use includes function in javascript which can provide you the output wheter the userage exists in your array or not! like this "validanswerone.includes(userage)" and better approach would be if you are creating an array just for multiple forms of YES or NO (you can just check it by using .tolower or .toCapital function)

Answer (score 0):

If the array contains only strings values you can use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if your array contains objects like this [ {id:1,name:"Aditya"} ] . then you should use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) since it applies comparrison logic while iterating through event element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for solving my problem!
here is the solution to the problem.
by converting all the input taken to an uppercase or an lower case using

```
var age = userage.toUpperCase();
```

i was able to take input in any format the input which is automatically converted into my condition which in this case is uppercase.

kindly someone help me rephrase the question properly and post the answer so some one needing this answer will be able to find it easily.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
//question asked to the user
var userage = readlineSync.question("Are you above the age of 18 for the purchase of the tickets \n(*as of DEC-2020) " + " : ");
var age = userage.toUpperCase();


//valid input to be taken by user
var validanswerone = "YES";
var validanswertwo = "NO";

//conditions
if (age === validanswerone){
  console.log("\n\nPlease put your credit card details in the next page" + ", you will be redirected soon!");
}
else if(age === validanswertwo){
  console.log("\n\nWe are sorry!");
  console.log("\n\nPlease try back in" + "  *days remaining to be become 18+ will be added in the coming update still not understood the formula to implicate it*");
}
else{
  console.log("\n\nInvalid input!")
}


//final-output
console.log("\n\nThank you, you will be redirected soon!")
```

Hope this solves some problem of someone someday!